# django rest framework nested objects get or create behaviour

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am creating an api end point using django-rest-framework for a specific json input. I have two related models like so (let's assume post can only have one category):

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    slug = models.SlugField()


class Post(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey()
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    text = models.CharField(max_length=256)
```

and my serializer are simple model serializers:

```
class CategorySerializer(ModelSerializer):
    id = serializers.IntegerField(required=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Category


class PostSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    id = serializers.IntegerField(required=True)
    category = CategorySerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = Post
```

and my api view is very simple also:

```
class PostAPIView(mixins.CreateModelMixin, GenericAPIView):
    serializer_class = PostSerializer
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
```

now in order to create posts I need to parse a json input like this:

```
{
    "id": 10,
    "pk": 10
    "title": "Some title",
    "text": "Some text",
    "category": {
        "id": 15,
        "pk": 15
        "name": "Best category",
        "slug": "best-category"
    }
}
```

in here 'pk' parameters are crucial for me, I want data to be created on my db using exact pk provided in json. Now if I make a post request and there are no posts with id:10 and categories with id:15 all is fine and data is written to db new records get inserted, but if there are any when rest-framework returns an error like ['Post id 10 already exists'], I would like matching records to be updated according to input instead. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add the **UpdateMixin**, just import it like the **CreateModelMixin**.
This mixin will implement the update and partial update methods, that will do what you want.
But you can not send a **POST**, for it you will need a **PUT**, or **PATCH**. You you want to do this on **POST**, I recommend you to implement your own create view method.

Comment: if I add put/patch then rest framework requires look_up fields and model for the view I created and since I am working with multiple models with this input, I cannot provide them..